# Ansible script module throws syntax error

Tags: ansible

[image: playbook image]

Ansible syntax validation throws error message as below:

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often
indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/mgdbplybks/test.yml': line 16,
column 5, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
  - name: launch mongod replA
    ^ here
=====================================================
```

If I comment out the script module, syntax check is okay.

Comment: Please do not add images when text is enough. It makes questions unsearchable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add two actions (modules) to a single task in Ansible.

You need to split `script` and `shell` into two tasks.

Answer (score 0):

> no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name

As the error says, you have a `-name` that is empty.

```
tasks:
- name: launch mongod replA
- script:...
```

The script is a second task. The first is empty.

Did you mean this?

```
tasks:
- name: launch mongod replA
  script: /scripts/mgdbscripts/replsetA.sh
```

Comment: name is not empty. It has the script module as action. Attached image of the playbook

Comment: You had `-name: ...`, then `-script: ... shell:`... The `-` character lists each task to be done. Since you had `-script`, then the `-name` task did nothing, as the error says

Comment: There were two actions/modules being used in one task. Changing that fixed the issue. Regarding the usage of -...that might be okay. YAML syntax http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html

Comment: Your original question had an empty named task **and** two actions in one. I only addressed the first of those problems